# SSRS - Report Summary Detail display formatting

Tags: reporting-services

I've been fiddling around with SSRS and going through google search for a solution, but haven't had much luck. My SQL queires are running fine, however trying to get it to display in a specific way on SSRS was a challenge.

I basically have a detail query and a summary query based on a grouping and my goal is to display the summary and the grouping per page on SSRS, hopefully the data and format below explains it.

Currently have the following data:

- **Name, ID, Amount, Grouping Code**
- Joe Bloggs, ABC, $50.00, GRP123
- Mary Jane, ABB, $150.00, GRP123
- Donald Duck, CCC, $50.00, GRP123
- Dick Tracey, ANN, $150.00, GRP222
- Micky Mouse, BCC, $50.00, GRP222
- Billy Bob, BCS, $150.00, GRP321
- Donkey Kong, BBD, $50.00, GRP321

The goal is to be able to produce a report to display as follows:

**Page 1:**

- **Summary**

  - GRP123, $250.00
- **Detail**

  - Joe Bloggs, ABC, $50.00
  - Mary Jane, ABB, $150.00
  - Donald Duck, CCC, $50.00

**Page 2:**

- **Summary**

  - GRP222, $200.00
- **Detail**

  - Dick Tracey, ANN, $150.00
  - Micky Mouse, BCC, $50.00

**Page 3:**

- **Summary**

  - GRP321, $200.00
- **Detail**

  - Billy Bob, BCS, $150.00
  - Donkey Kong, BBD, $50.00

**What I'm actually getting:**

**Page 1:**

- **Summary**

  - GRP123, $250.00

**Page 2:**

- **Summary**

  - GRP222, $200.00

**Page 3:**

- **Summary**

  - GRP321, $200.00
- **Detail**

  - Joe Bloggs, ABC, $50.00
  - Mary Jane, ABB, $150.00
  - Donald Duck, CCC, $50.00

**Page 4:**

- **Detail**

  - Dick Tracey, ANN, $150.00
  - Micky Mouse, BCC, $50.00

**Page 5:**

- **Detail**

  - Billy Bob, BCS, $150.00
  - Donkey Kong, BBD, $50.00

The data is correct, however the way it's grouping/displaying is all whacked.
- I've tried having 2 queries one to produce the detail and one to produce the summary and also tried joining them into 1 big table, but the results are still not correct.

Has anyone experienced anything similar or has a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for two result sets.  Using the single result set listed above assigned to your tablix, create the group on your GroupingCode.  When creating the group, Mark the checkbox to `Add group header`

[image]

or if you already have the group set up, you can simply add a `Total` before the detail row

[image]

ps - screenshots go a long way to understanding the problem

Comment: Hi trubs, thanks for your response, I'll try that out.

Comment: [Update] Looks good, now just got to make the labels... inserted a row between the Total and the Detail and noticed the headers kept generating for each detail, I might need to play around with it. Thanks heaps!